# Can O(n + logn) be called O(n)?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I know that O(n + 5) would be classified as a worst-case runtime of O(n), but can I do that with logn too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $O(n+\log n)$ and $O(n)$ are *the same complexity class*, because $n+\log n\in O(n)$ and $n\in O(n+\log n)$.